# Required field error happans only when using ajax

Tags: django, ajax, django-forms

**I have a model named SaleEntry:**

```
class SaleEntry(models.Model):
date = models.DateField()
ebay_price = models.FloatField()
amazon_price = models.FloatField()
ebay_tax = models.FloatField()
paypal_tax = models.FloatField()
tm_fee = models.FloatField(default=0.3)
promoted = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
profit = models.FloatField()
discount = models.FloatField(default=0)
country = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="-----")
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:  # object is being created, thus no primary key field yet
        change_balance = Balance.objects.get(user=self.user)
        change_balance.balance = change_balance.balance - self.amazon_price - self.tm_fee + self.discount
        change_balance.save()
    
    super(SaleEntry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def calc_profit(self):
    return self.ebay_price - self.amazon_price - self.ebay_tax - self.paypal_tax - self.tm_fee - self.promoted + self.discount

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user} - {self.profit}'
```

**And I have a form handling this model SaleEntryForm:**

```
class SaleEntryForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = SaleEntry
    fields = "__all__"
    widgets = {
        'date': DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id':'f_date'}),
        'ebay_price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'eBay Price', 'id':'f_ebay_price', 'onkeyup': 'calc_profit()'}),
        'amazon_price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Amazon Price', 'id':'f_amazon_price', 'onkeyup': 'calc_profit()'}),
        'ebay_tax': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-1', 'placeholder': 'eBay Tax', 'id':'f_ebay_tax', 'onkeyup': 'calc_profit()'}),
        'paypal_tax': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-1', 'placeholder': 'Paypal Tax', 'id':'f_paypal_tax', 'onkeyup': 'calc_profit()'}),
        'tm_fee': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-1', 'placeholder': 'TM Fee', 'id':'f_tm_fee', 'onkeyup': 'calc_profit()'}),
        'promoted': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-1', 'placeholder': 'Promoted', 'id':'f_promoted', 'onkeyup': 'calc_profit()'}),
        'profit': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Profit', 'readonly':'true', 'id':'f_profit'}),
        'discount': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Discount', 'id':'f_discount'}),
        'country': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Country', 'id':'f_country'}),
    }

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    '''
    relate the sale registration form to the user who created it.
    '''
    user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id')
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['user'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(id=user_id), empty_label=None, initial=User.objects.get(id=user_id))
    self.fields['user'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'no-display'
```

**I am using this form in the html page:**

```
<form id="form_add_sale">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <tr>
                {% for field in form %}
                    {% if field is not form.user %}
                    <td>
                        {{ field }}
                    </td>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ field }}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" display="inline" name="btn_register_sale"></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
```

**and this is the ajax to send the data to server:**

```
$(document).on("submit", '#form_add_sale', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
         
    $.ajax({
        url:"{% url 'add_sale' %}",
        type:"POST",
        data:{
            date: $("#f_date").val(),
            ebay_price: $("#f_ebay_price").val(),
            amazon_price: $("#f_amazon_price").val(),
            ebay_tax: $("#f_ebay_tax").val(),
            paypal_tax: $("#f_paypal_tax").val(),
            tm_fee: $("#f_tm_fee").val(),
            promoted: $("#f_promoted").val(),
            profit: $("#f_profit").val(),
            discount: $("#f_discount").val(),
            country: $("#f_country").val(),
        },
        success: function(){
            alert("Created new sale!");
        }
    })
    //.done(function(response){
    //    $("#table_sales").load(location.href + " #table_sales");
    //})
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error){
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
    })
})
```

**upon submitting the form, I'm getting the next error (which didn't occur when submitting the form regularly without ajax with the exact same code in the view):**

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>user<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

**this is the request.POST:**

<QueryDict: {'date': ['2021-02-11'], 'ebay_price': ['70'], 'amazon_price': ['50'], 'ebay_tax': ['10'], 'paypal_tax': ['5'], 'tm_fee': ['0.3'], 'promoted': ['0.0'], 'profit': ['4.70'], 'discount': ['0'], 'country': ['-----']}>

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the `csrf_token`. try adding:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
```

to the `data`.

More information can be found [here](https://dev.to/coderasha/how-to-send-django-form-with-ajax-4bpo)

Comment: In fact, I did it with the decorator I just didn't solve it. anyway, I solved the problem I just needed to exclude the user field and add it from the view. Thanks anyway!